# For each entry into text box, an alert show pop up using jquery

Tags: jquery

For each enter or for every entry into the text box I want the alert to be triggered

```
<input type="text" id="val_xml" class="val_xml1" maxlength="3" size="2"/>


$('#val_xml').bind('change',function() {
    var v = $('#val_xml').val();
    alert(v);
});
```

Thanks
Jean

Comment: Can you be more clear? You want 1 alert for each character?

Comment: @Bruno - I would assume OP wants an alert when the enter key is pressed, on blur, and also when the maximum number of characters are entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to work.

Make sure to include a doc ready / Script tags, etc. And if you want an automatic alert once **the maximum number of characters are entered**:

```
​$(function() {
    $('#val_xml').bind('change',function() {            
        alert(this.value);

        // These alerts can get annoying. If you are done with it, unbind it:
        // $(this).unbind(arguments[0]); // <== would unbind this alert
     });

      // Check if max chars entered at each keyup
    $(document).keyup(function() {
        var $valXML = $("#val_xml");
        if ($valXML.val().length >= $valXML.attr("maxlength") )
            $valXML.trigger("change");
    });
});​
```

### [Try it out with this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uSfwB/)

The above does one alert for each "entry".  This means that the alert is triggered by blurring, by pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>, or when 3 chars (the max) are entered.

Note that each time you write `$('#val_xml')` you create a new jQuery object. So in your code, you create the exact same jQuery object twice. Additionally, there's no need to use a jQuery method to access the `value` property of a DOM element, which is why I use `this.value`.

**References:**
**[`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**
**[`.keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)**
**[`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#val_xml').bind('change keyup',function() {
    var v = $(this).val();
    alert(v);
});
```

Comment: Your code will not work. `$this` is undefined. You probably meant `$(this)`, but `this.value` is the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/keyup/ and .focus() if you want "each enter or for every entry"

Answer (score 0):

For text boxes, the `change` event is [only fired when the element loses focus](http://api.jquery.com/change/).  If you want this function to execute each time a new character is added, bind to the `keypress` event instead of `change`.

`keydown` and `keyup` could also be used, but please note that these will only fire once, even if the user holds down the key so that multiple characters are added.  `keypress` will fire once for each added character.

Comment: Like @Peter mentioned above, this would be very dysfunctional, but my answer assumes you want this function fired for every keypress for some reason and that the alert() call is just for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

use the keyup event.

```
$('#val_xml').keyup(function() {
    var v = $('#val_xml').val();
    alert(v);
});
```